# Why isn't Gnome Color applying my color profile?

Tags: gnome, monitor, colors

I'm trying to use the Gnome Color (default Color app in `/usr/bin/gnome-control-center.real color`) to manage my laptop's color profile. However, only *some* of the color profile actually change the display colors!

For instance, PJD7820HD, E551i-A2, EQ276W HDMI, Projector, DVX-3150, D65 and Swapped Red and Green (!) all display the same colors. Whereas Blue, D50, and D55 are the only profiles that change the display colors.

Why is it that some of the profiles work, but some don't? I noticed that in the description for Blue, it says it works by "altering the video card lookup table" - maybe this is what D50 and D55 do as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it's the difference between calibration and characterization profiles described here: [What's the difference between calibration and characterization?](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/color-calibrationcharacterization.html.en)

More info here: [Missing information for whole-screen color correction?](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/color-missingvcgt.html.en)

> Unfortunately, many vendor-supplied ICC profiles do not include the information required for whole-screen color correction. These profiles can still be useful for applications that can do color compensation, but you will not see all the colors of your screen change.

You can also see that in all of the profiles that do change your screen color that the "Display correction" in the View Details window is "yes" where in the profiles that don't change it are "no".  In the case of profile D65 which does have display correction, the correction seems to be only have a very slight change or no change when looking at the VCGT tab in the details window.