# Does Ubuntu support Intel Graphics Command Center or similar software?

Tags: drivers, graphics, software-center

I am running Windows 10 at the moment and the only thing which is stopping me from switching to Ubuntu is the uncertainty weather I could change my display color settings or not. The stock settings are washed out and flat on my screen and I prefer more punchy colours. Please help me find a tool like Intel Graphics Control Center because the difference is night and day for me!

Comment: Nothing on Intel's website suggests that they make this software to work on Ubuntu. What does the software actually do? The description from Intel is extremely vague.  Did you know that you can "Try Ubuntu" by booting installation media without affecting your installed system?

Comment: I think you need to come at this from a different perspective. Instead of asking "can I install a windows application" you need to ask "how do I do this/that on ubuntu?" instead. 99.9% of the time, we're able to customize and alter the system in ways not possible on windows, even with specialized software.

Comment: I agree with @mchid You approach this the wrong way and should abandon this idea. Linux is different. Non-desktop settings (think system, server, and hardware related) we do command line style by altering configuration files or issueing a command, That lets us tweak far more than Microsoft allows you to do on Windows using a graphical tool.

Comment: could this be what you are looking for: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color.html.en

Answer (score 1):

**First**, [Go to System Settings and under Hardware, click on Color.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-assignprofiles.html.en)

**Then**, click on your device and at the bottom of the settings window, click on "Add Profile". Here, there are dozens of profiles to choose from.

**After you select a profile**, click on the profile listed under the device and then click View Details to view details on the profile.

Many of these profiles will not change the look of the screen. For my particular monitor, **D50, D55, and D65** work well aside from the default profile. [You can read more about that here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622119/why-isnt-gnome-color-applying-my-color-profile) but you'll have to try them out to be sure. Also, google your hardware and color profiles for "Ubuntu" or "Linux" to see if others have tested this out already.

The profile will switch automatically and you should notice a change in the look immediately. If you don't notice a change, try a different profile.

**You can read more detailed information** at [the Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color.html.en). As for calibration, automatic calibration (clicking on the calibration button) may not be available on certain screens (I think mostly LCD screens?).

**You can also use/install the gnome color manager** from the gnome software center. This is similar but the GUI is slightly different. Search for "color profile manager" to find the app.

**Furthermore**, there are [command line tools like xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370153/how-can-i-improve-color-saturation-in-ubuntu) that allow you to adjust color manually although I think this doesn't work with Wayland so you'll probably have to use this particular solution on non-wayland sessions (X11) only (google how to select between wayland or x11 for ubuntu).

---

**See also:**

[this related answer (may be outdated for Wayland users)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756082/how-to-adjust-screen-settings-contrast-color-saturation-etc)

[a similar answer using Gnome Color Manager (basically follows the same process using a different GUI)](https://askubuntu.com/a/370167/167115)

---

**If nothing else works**, some users report that Redshift is working on Wayland but as far as I know, Wayland is not officially supported and other people report crashes and glitches. A safe alternative would be to use [X11 instead of Wayland](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04) when using Redshift.

You can install Redshift using the following command(s):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install redshift redshift-gtk
```

and [you can read more about setting up your config file here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Redshift#Manual_setup). To start Redshift, simply search for Redshift in your list of installed applications. After it starts, there should be an icon on your top dash bar where you can click and enable or disable automatic startup. The workaround here would be to always set Redshift to a daytime temperature for both night and day.

Comment: I googled "does xrandr work on wayland" and I found this answer on reddit which mentions a few tools and alternatives. Wayland is kind of new on Ubuntu (about 4 years old) so many answers may be for X11, you should still be able to find info if you search for answers involving the specific tools mentioned. Also, Google "Ubuntu manpage" followed by the command or package name to locate the Ubuntu manpage instructions for more info.

Comment: To search for packages like kanshi for example, try to install the package with `sudo apt install kanshi` or run `apt-cache search kanshi` or `apt-cache show kanshi` to search for or show info respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I did not include the link in my previous comment. [Here is the answer I found on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wayland/comments/kuiqcl/xrandr_equivalent_on_wayland/)